# Device orientation change issue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My `viewController1` has a child view controller (`viewController2`). `viewController2.view` is a subview of `viewController1`'s view. At the user's action, I remove the view of `viewController2` from it's superview. After a while I have to add it again as subview.

The problem is that if the user rotates the device while `viewController2` is not visible, after adding it again to viewController1's view, it's frame and it's subviews are placed as the device was still in the old orientation. Even the `viewController2.view.frame` has the height and with interchanged.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I would guess that you are keeping a reference to view controller 2 even when it isn't visible.  In that case, you need to forward the view rotation events to the controller so that it knows about the rotation like this (Do this for each event that you want to forward):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    // Forward to view controller 2 if it is not displayed
    if (!viewController2.view) {
        [viewController2 willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    }
}
```

A better design may be to just set view controller 2's view to `hidden` instead of removing it, and it will still get the events without manual intervention.

Comment: Thanks, it did the job. Just out of curiosity, how would I forward the  view rotation events to viewController2 (and yes, I have a reference to it)?

Comment: I added an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess your problem. Do you want to show the different UIView base on orientation , right?

It's about update your `viewController2` to load the nib base on orientation. You can make the landscape and portrait nib to support your different UI due to orientation. Try to look from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734710/696088)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I have a VC that is not on screen when the user rotates the device. When it appears, it behaves like it would be in the old orientation (when it disappeared)